# Solve 3D Electric Field Using FEA

Tags: finite-element-method, electromagnetics

The objective is to solve the 3D electric fields for the geometry below and generate the continuous function `eField3D[x_,y_,z_]`. The method I was planning on using was FEA to solve Laplace PDEs.

I have the following mesh generation code:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

cylinOffset = 0.032;
cylinLength = 0.100;
cylinRadius = 0.001;

shellLength = 0.100;
shellRadius = 0.0365;

cylinA = Cylinder[{{-cylinOffset, 0, -cylinLength /2}, 
         {-cylinOffset, 0, cylinLength /2}}, cylinRadius];
cylinB = Cylinder[{{cylinOffset, 0, -cylinLength /2}, 
         {cylinOffset, 0, cylinLength /2}}, cylinRadius];

shell = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -shellLength /2}, {0, 0, shellLength /2}}, shellRadius];

bmeshShell = ToBoundaryMesh[shell]["Wireframe"];
bmeshCylinA = ToBoundaryMesh[cylinA]["Wireframe"];
bmeshCylinB = ToBoundaryMesh[cylinB]["Wireframe"];

Show[bmeshShell, bmeshCylinA, bmeshCylinB]
```

[image]

I'm quite confused on how to progress further. The following is an attempt to setup the boundary conditions of voltage potential and region where the equations should be evaluated, but I'm far away from a solution. Guidance would be very much appreciated.

```
reg = {bmeshShell, bmeshCylinA, bmeshCylinB};
sol = NDSolveValue[{Inactive[Laplacian][u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
      DirichletCondition[bmeshShell == 0, 
      bmeshCylinA == bmeshCylinB == 30000]}, 
      u, {x, y, z} \[Element] reg];
```

Comment: How do your boundary conditions work?  Are you saying you want the function `u[x, y, z]` to be zero at the `bmeshShell` boundary and 30000 at the other two boundaries?  I think the syntax of your `DirichletCondition` is not correct

Comment: Yes. Zero potential at the shell and 30 000 at each cylinder. I'm sure DirichletCondition is wrong and the region isn't setup correctly either. I'm working on figuring out the region definition now.

Comment: I *think* it should be more like this, `sol = NDSolveValue[{Inactive[Laplacian][u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, bmeshShell], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 30000, bmeshCylinA], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 30000, bmeshCylinB]}, 
  u, {x, y, z} \[Element] shell]` but I still don't get it to give me an answer.  Maybe we can get @user21 to take a look at this, he's the expert

Comment: Try a 2D example first and the extend that to 3D. Also, `reg = {bmeshShell, bmeshCylinA, bmeshCylinB}` is not how it works. I think I'd start expressing the region as an `ImplicitRegion`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using user21's advice, I built the 2D model of the system then expanded it to 3D.

Here is the general 3D solution:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

cylinLength = 73.0;
cylinRadius =  1.0;
cylinBuffer =  5.0;
cylinOffset = 32.0;
shellRadius = 36.5;

cylinVoltage = 30000;

shell = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -cylinLength/2}, {0, 0, cylinLength/2}}, shellRadius];
cylin = RegionUnion[
   Cylinder[{{-cylinOffset, 0, -cylinLength/2}, {-cylinOffset, 0, 
      cylinLength/2}}, cylinRadius],
   Cylinder[{{cylinOffset, 0, -cylinLength/2}, {cylinOffset, 0, 
      cylinLength/2}}, cylinRadius]];

region = RegionDifference[shell, cylin];

solMV = NDSolveValue[
  {D[u[x, y, z], x, x] + D[u[x, y, z], y, y] + D[u[x, y, z], z, z] == 0,
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, z^2 == (cylinLength/2)^2],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, 
     x^2 + y^2 == shellRadius^2 && z^2 < (cylinLength/2)^2 + (cylinBuffer)^2],
    DirichletCondition[
     u[x, y, z] == 
      cylinVoltage, (x + cylinOffset)^2 + y^2 == cylinRadius^2 && 
      z^2 < (cylinLength/2)^2 + (cylinBuffer)^2],
    DirichletCondition[
     u[x, y, z] == 
      cylinVoltage, (x - cylinOffset)^2 + y^2 == cylinRadius^2 && 
      z^2 < (cylinLength/2)^2 + (cylinBuffer)^2]},
   u, {x, y, z} ∈ region, InterpolationOrder -> All, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 1}}];

solME[x_, y_, z_] = -Grad[solMV[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];

Show[
 SliceContourPlot3D[solMV[x, y, z], 
  "CenterPlanes", {x, y, z} ∈ sol["ElementMesh"], Contours -> 20, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 VectorPlot3D[
  solME[x, y, z], {x, -shellRadius, shellRadius}, {y, -shellRadius, 
   shellRadius}, {z, -cylinLength/2, cylinLength/2}, 
  VectorStyle -> Red, VectorPoints -> Fine]
 ]
```

[image]

Improvements welcome.

Comment: When I tried the code above, it threw numerous NDSolveValue errors.  Is there a missing initialization or code in the example above?

Comment: The primary errors are ToElementMesh::femtemnbb and NDSolveValue::bcnoop. ToElementMesh::femtemnbb is generated when no numeric bounds can be computed for a region. For the code above, there are no places on the boundaries that satisfy the Dirichlet conditions.